# SOQL Statement with Uppercase Function

Tags: apex, soql

Is there a uppercase function in SOQL?  For example,

> Select uppercase(Country_Name__c) from Account;

I need to match user input (Country_Name__c) to my Map and return market.  It only works if the user enter in the exact case (United States and not united states).

```
trigger leadMarketAssignment on Lead(before insert, before update)
{     
Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c> mMap = New Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c>();

For(Country_Market_Map__c m: [SELECT Id, uppercase(Country_Name__c), Market__c FROM Country_Market_Map__c]){
    mMap.put(m.Country_Name__c,m);
}    

for (Lead l : Trigger.new){
    if(l.country__c <> ''){
        if(mMap.containsKey(l.country__c)){
             l.Market__c = mMap.get(l.country__c).Market__c; 
        }
    }
}////

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with data retrieval. Your records should be getting retrieved correctly as in SOQL "=" comparison is case-insisitive. As mentioned by others in above comments, you should use "toUpperCase()" method.

You should try following code:-

```
Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c> mMap = New Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c>();

For(Country_Market_Map__c m: [SELECT Id, Country_Name__c, Market__c FROM Country_Market_Map__c]){
    mMap.put(m.Country_Name__c.toupperCase(),m);
}

for (Lead l : Trigger.new){
    if(l.country__c <> ''){
        if(mMap.containsKey(l.country__c)){
            l.Market__c = mMap.get(l.country__c.toupperCase()).Market__c; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After updating my code to the suggestion above.  It compiles without error but when I enter country = united states it pops this error: accMarketAssignment: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.accMarketAssignment: line 14, column 1

Comment: ignore my previous comment.  It is working.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just convert to upper case when you are adding it to the map?

```
  mMap.put(m.Country_Name__c.toUpperCase(),m);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 2019 and I think this question deserves and update. I don't know how this was working before but if one does the comparison with the `like` instead of `=` you get the match. The `like` is case insensitive were `=` is case sensitive. If you do `where "JOHN" like "john"` you get a match.

Docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

Comment: Both comparisons are case insensitive, so this answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: *String comparisons using the equals operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive fields and case-insensitive for all other fields.* Saying that the `=` comparison is always case-sensitive is just not true.

Comment: Go to the https://workbench.developerforce.com/ and write a query where the record is all uppercase and your var is another case like so... `/services/data/v46.0/query?q=select+Id,LastName+from+Lead+where+LastName+Like+%27MyName%27` and see the you will match the record.

Comment: Yes but the `=` comparison operator would work just as well. I am not saying `LIKE` is case-sensitive. Where you are *incorrect* is your assertion that all `=` comparisons are case-sensitive.